# Reusing Fragments/Bottomsheets with viewModel as data binding variable

Tags: android, mvvm, data-binding, android-viewmodel

I will give an example so as to easily explain my problem.

Consider `FragmentA` with `ViewModelA` and `FragmentB` with `ViewModelB` being used in my app.

I have a `BottomSheetSample` that is to be used in both `FragmentA` and `FragmentB` Since the bottom sheet is doing very little, like selecting a value I want to share the ViewModel of the fragment on which the bottom sheet is being displayed on, instead of having a separate ViewModel and transferring the data to the `ViewModel` of the `fragment`. I am binding the `ViewModel` like this to the nav graph.

Inside `FragmentA`

```
private val viewModel: ViewModelA by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_A_graph) { viewModelFactory }
```

Inside `BottomSheetSample`

```
private val viewModel: ViewModelA by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_A_graph) { viewModelFactory }
```

I am passing the `ViewModel` to the XML like this so as to use it with data-binding:

```
val binding: BottomSheetSampleBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.bottomSheet, container, false)
binding.viewModel = viewModel
```

sample bottom sheet XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.ui.fragmenta.ViewModelA" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.oneSelected()} />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.twoSelected()} />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now the issue is that I have to use the same Bottom Sheet(`BottomSheetSample`) in `FragmentB` also. Since I am passing the `ViewModel` to the XML for data binding, I am not able to use the same bottom sheet as the current `BottomSheetSampleBinding` is expecting an object of `ViewModelA`.

So what I end up doing is creating a new `BottomSheetSampleB` which does exactly the same thing as `BottomSheetSample` and just change the ViewModel in the new XML to `ViewModelB` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.ui.fragmentb.ViewModelB" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.oneSelected()} />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.twoSelected()} />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now if I have to use the same BottomSheet in a third fragment I have to copy the BottomSheetSample and do the whole thing again. This looks redundant as the same bottom sheet is being replicated again and again. But I don't know how to avoid doing this. Can someone tell me the right way to do this?

Hopefully, I am clear about my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `BaseViewModel` (Any name) and keep all the things required for bottom sheet in `BaseViewModel` . Use this BaseViewModel in Bottom Sheet

```
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.ui.fragmentb.BaseViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.oneSelected()}" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.twoSelected()}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Extend your `ViewModelA`,`ViewModelB`   with the `BaseViewModel`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me try it and get back to you

Comment: Thanks Manohar.. I can't for the life of me figure out why I didn't think of this.